# Can I solve my decision problem in $O(n)$ time?

Tags: algorithms, strings

*My algorithm solves a custom string problem but it loops twice making it $O(n^2)$ time. I'm asking here as I'm a beginner in self-learning algorithms.*

Decision Problem: Given an input list $A$, can our target string $S$ be made from any of the elements of $A$?

If just one element does not exist in $A$ (which exists in $s$) then the algorithm returns false.

```
A = input_array
s = input_target_array

for i in s:
  if i in A:
    (all elements ∈ s) ∈ A
  else:
    break  

(if any element ∈ s) ∉ A:
  return False
else:
  return True
```

**Output**

```
Enter your input for A and include spaces:
Enter letters WITH SPACES: "ab" "cd" "ac"
enter your input for s:
 "abxd"
^ False ^
 "abcd"
^ True ^
```

I'm looking for an algorithm that solves my made up decision problem faster than $O(n^2)$ time.

### Question

Are there any methods that can be used from an algorithmic standpoint that would make this $O(n)$ time?

Comment: How large is the alphabet?  Should we treat the size of the alphabet as constant ($O(1)$) or not?

Comment: @D.W. The alphabet could be any of the infinite ones out there. Sometimes I use smiley faces and pineapples as a character string.

Comment: what does `(all elements ∈ s) ∈ A` mean in code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4642172/781723, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/95996/755

Comment: @user253751 Suppose that you see that the elements in $s$ as in the output example contains a character x. Since $A$ does not contain a character x then "(if any element ∈ s) ∉ A" is True (algorithm returns false).

Comment: @TravisWells that's nice and all but I didn't ask that. What does `(all elements ∈ s) ∈ A` mean in code?

Comment: @user253751 It means that "all elements in $s$ are in $A$."

Comment: @TravisWells So what does it mean as a statement? If all the elements in $s$ are ***not*** in $A$ - let's say $s=\{1,2,3,4\}, A=\{5,6,7,8\}$, and then the computer executes `(all elements ∈ s) ∈ A`, what are the new contents of $s$ and $A$?

Comment: @user253751 Then the statement returns false. Because one or more elements in s are not in A.

Comment: @TravisWells What does returning false mean? The value is not used. It's not in an `if` or `while` or anything. So it doesn't do anything? You could delete it and the program would still do the same thing?

Answer (score 2):

I use set difference to find out if there are any elements in $s$ that don't exist in $A$. This should be $O(n)$ in the best cases if there is a good hash. Since I'm dealing with integers it should be $O(n)$ [Explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48044353/what-is-the-run-time-of-the-set-difference-function-in-python)

I then use $len(s)$ and $len(A)$ which takes $O(1)$ time [according to here](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/ICS-33/lectures/complexitypython.txt).

```
A = [1,2,3,4,9]
s = [1,2,3,4,9]

elem_not_in_A = set(s) - set(A)

if len(s) >= len(A):
    if len(elem_not_in_A) > 0:
        output False
    else:
        output True
else:
    output False
```

If the set difference remains $O(n)$ and all the other statements remain $O(1)$ then yes it can be solved in $O(n)$ time.